# Hair particles laying flat on hills

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

I am trying to make grass using hair particles. When I add hills to my scene the grass/hair lays flat - I need them to stay vertical.

Here's a picture and my .blend file. What's going on? I have looked everywhere for an answer over the past 3 days. [image: Hair laying flat.]

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-keJ_TGYZNONWdKaGZWSkJ6dlk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the particle panel, click on advanced, then in the velocity section, lower the normal strength and grow the Z strength :

[image]